# is it possible for 2 domain names to use one azure web app with application gateway and how?

Tags: azure

I have 2 domains I want to use with one web app. I want all traffic to be routed via the app gateway.

I have set up 2 example domains www.myfirstdomain.com www.mysecondomain.com

I have verified these websites in my azure web app and added each hostname to the web app.

I have created virtual directories in the web app as follows

- /one -> site\wwwroot\one
- /two -> site\wwwroot\two

When I type in www.www.myfirstdomain.com I want this to go to the /one directory when I type in www.myseconddomain.com I want this to go the /two directory

Does the app gateway need to have multi site listeners and path based rules, is only one backendpool required?

Comment: You can host only one Website in a single Azure web app. Even though you create two virtual directories, it won't work like that as simple

Comment: based on my knowledge you need only 1 backendpool and multisite listeners. I'm not sure about the webapp part, though. Appgateway part will work 101%.

Comment: A simpler solution could be to use two web apps. Any reason you are putting both in one?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure the concept of a web server is the underlying App Service Plan, on top of that each virtual directory is a web app. You can have multiple web apps per Service Plan. So the usual solution is to have a separate web app for each distinct website you have. You can attach multiple domain names to each app, but they will all point to the same code.